# How to replace "--" with blank

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have a test.csv like so:

```
83451031,2019-07-04,0,0,0,0,--,0,--,0,0,0,,,,--,--,--,--,--,--,--,--,,,,,,,,,,
1730632031,2019-07-05,0.6023,3200000,0.1789,0.1768,June,0.0097,5,381.1,515.4,46300,11.67,68.97,19.36,4.33,67.51,22953,49,0.0053,Typical,8.3,377,,--,--,,--,--,,--,--,
```

I want to replace `--` with nothing i.e. blank

I've tried the following:

```sh
$ sed 's/--/' test.csv > test.csv
$ sed -i 's/--/' test.csv
$ sed -i "s/--/" test.csv
$ sed -i "s/--//" test.csv
$ sed -i "s/--//g" test.csv
$ sed -i "s/'--'//" test.csv
$ sed -i "s/'--'//g" test.csv
$ sed -i "s/'--'/''/" test.csv
```

All of which gives an error of:

```
sed: 1: "test.csv": undefined label 'est.csv'
```

Since `--` signifies the end of command options, I assume that's the problem?

I just want to be able to replace all occurrences of `--` in the CSV to blank.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
sed 's#--#  #g'
```

Demo:

```
$echo 5"83451031,2019-07-04,0,0,0,0,--,0,--,0,0,0,,,,--,--,--,--,--,--,--,--,,,,,,,,,,"  | sed 's#--#  #g' 
583451031,2019-07-04,0,0,0,0,  ,0,  ,0,0,0,,,,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,  ,,,,,,,,,,
$
```

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's quesion IMO. OP is using `sed` from MacOS, which is causing errors because of not providing the inplace extension

Comment: That works in terms of display output but when trying to output to file it removes everything i.e. `sed 's#--#  #g' test.csv > test.csv` returns an empty test.csv file

Comment: @AK91: You cannot re-direct to the same file. The `>test.csv` empties the file before running `sed`. Use the `-i.bak` or `-i ''` option for inplace edit. See the linked question